Gutenberg block selected state
I have Gutenberg block which shows list of playlists in select element and then when  select element si changed I want to retrieve list of songs in that playlist. For this I use ajax with WordPress and call getPlaylistMedia function.
This needs to happen on start and when select is changed (thats why I have 2 getPlaylistMedia call).
The problem si that Gutenberg edit is called twice, bith when I select and deselet element with mouse in edit page. In other words this happens:
edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
    console.log(attributes, setAttributes)
    ....

I want to call getPlaylistMedia only when element is selected (not deselected).
Is there a callback or property I can use to detect when element is selected?
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

"use strict"

const { __ } = wp.i18n;
const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
const el = wp.element.createElement;



var IconBlock = function(e) {
    return wp.element.createElement("svg", {
        xmlns: "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
        "xmlns:xlink": "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",
        width: "20",
        height: "20",
        viewBox: "0 0 512 512",
        class: "dashicon my-block-icon"
    }, [wp.element.createElement("path", {
        id: "a",
        d: "M256 32C114.52 32 0 146.496 0 288v48a32 32 0 0 0 17.689 28.622l14.383 7.191C34.083 431.903 83.421 480 144 480h24c13.255 0 24-10.745 24-24V280c0-13.255-10.745-24-24-24h-24c-31.342 0-59.671 12.879-80 33.627V288c0-105.869 86.131-192 192-192s192 86.131 192 192v1.627C427.671 268.879 399.342 256 368 256h-24c-13.255 0-24 10.745-24 24v176c0 13.255 10.745 24 24 24h24c60.579 0 109.917-48.098 111.928-108.187l14.382-7.191A32 32 0 0 0 512 336v-48c0-141.479-114.496-256-256-256z"
    })])
};

var i,
playlists = JSON.parse(map_block_data.playlists),
playlistArr = [{label:'Select playlist..', value:''}],
mediaArr = [{label:'Loading..', value:''}],
ajaxForMedia

for (i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++){
    playlistArr.push({label:playlists[i].title +' - ID #'+playlists[i].id, value:playlists[i].id})
}

class Button extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var e = document.location.origin + document.location.pathname.replace("post.php", "admin.php") + "?page=";
        return el("a", {
            href: e + this.props.href,
            target: "_blank",
            className: this.props.className
        }, this.props.text)
    }
}

registerBlockType( 'test-player/block', {
    title: "Test Player",
    description: "Powerful player for your website",
    icon: {
        src: IconBlock
    },
    category: 'common',
    keywords: [
        __( 'Test player' ),
        __( 'Sound' ),
        __( 'Song' ),
    ],
    attributes: {
        playlist_id : {
            type: 'string',
        },
        media_id : {
            type: 'string',
        }
    },
    edit({attributes, setAttributes}) {
        console.log(attributes, setAttributes)

        function onChangePlaylistId(v) {
            setAttributes( {playlist_id: v} );
            getPlaylistMedia({playlist_id: v})
        }

        function onChangeMediaId(v) {
            setAttributes( {media_id: v} );
        }

        if(attributes.playlist_id != undefined)getPlaylistMedia(attributes)

        return [

                el(
                    'div',
                    { className: 'test-block-container'},
                    el(IconBlock, {}), 
                    el("span", {}, "Test Player")
                ),

                el( wp.element.Fragment, {},
                    el( wp.blockEditor.InspectorControls, {},
                        el( wp.components.PanelBody, { title: 'Select source', initialOpen: true },

                            playlistArr.length == 1 ? 

                                el(Button, {
                                    href: "playlist_manager&action=add_playlist",
                                    className: "components-button is-button is-default is-large aptean-block-panel-button",
                                    text: __("Create new playlist")
                                })

                            : el(
                                wp.components.SelectControl,
                                {
                                    label: 'Select playlist',
                                    value: attributes.playlist_id,
                                    options: playlistArr,
                                    onChange: onChangePlaylistId
                                }
                            ), 

                            el(
                                wp.components.SelectControl,
                                {
                                    label: 'Select media',
                                    value: attributes.media_id,
                                    options: mediaArr,
                                    onChange: onChangeMediaId,
                                    className: "test-media-id-select",
                                }
                            ),    

                        ),
         
                    ),

                ), 
           
            ]


    },
    save(props) {

        var attributes = props.attributes, shortcode = '';

        if(attributes.playlist_id !== 'undefined'){
            shortcode += '[aptest playlist_id="' + attributes.playlist_id + '"';
        }
        if(attributes.media_id != undefined)shortcode += ' media_id="' + attributes.media_id + '"';

        shortcode += ']';

        return shortcode;

    },
} );

function getPlaylistMedia(atts){

    var postData = [
        {name: 'action', value: 'test_get_media'},
        {name: 'playlist_id', value: atts.playlist_id}
    ];

    if(ajaxForMedia){
        ajaxForMedia.abort()
        ajaxForMedia = null;
    }

    ajaxForMedia = $.ajax({
        url: test_block_data.ajax_url,
        type: 'post',
        data: postData,
        dataType: 'json',
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response)

        var i, len = response.length, obj, title, option = '<option value="">None</option>'
        for(i = 0; i< len; i++){
            obj = response[i]

            option += '<option value="'+obj.id+'">'+obj.title+' - ID #'+obj.id+'</option>'
            
        }

        var media_select = $('.test-media-id-select').find('select')
        media_select.html(option)

        if(atts.media_id != undefined){
            media_select.val(atts.media_id);
        }

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText, textStatus, errorThrown);
        isAjaxCall = false;
    }); 

}


});

